# Django - How to display GeoJSON on a Mapbox map?

Tags: javascript, django, mapbox

Using Django (v1.11) and Mapbox, I am trying to display a map with some GeoJSON content which I load from a local file. For example purposes I am using [this sample.json file](https://gist.github.com/wavded/1200773?short_path=99c1af9).

My idea was to load the GeoJSON file into a JSON object, and pass that to a template (in this case *map.html*). Additionally, I attempted to convert the JSON object into a string, pass that string, and then re-create a new JSON object with Javascript (shown below). Neither method has worked for me.

However, if I simply copy-paste the contents of *sample.json* as a Javascript variable, everything works and the GeoJSON is displayed correctly.

So my question is, how can I load the GeoJSON from a file, pass that to an HTML template, and then display the contents on a Mapbox map?

**views.py**

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    with open('/somepath/sample.json') as f:
        data = json.load(f)
    data = json.dumps(data)
    return render(request, 'map.html', {'data':data})
```

**map.html**

```
map.on('load', function () {

    // THIS DOES NOT WORK

    var json_data = JSON.parse({{ data }})

    map.addLayer({
        'id': 'layerid',
        'type': 'fill',
        'source': {
            'type': 'geojson',
            'data': json_data
        }
    });
});
```

**map.html**

```
map.on('load', function () {

    // THIS WORKS

    var json_data = { "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
      { "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [102.0, 0.5]},
        "properties": {"prop0": "value0"}
        },
      { "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
          "type": "LineString",
          "coordinates": [
            [102.0, 0.0], [103.0, 1.0], [104.0, 0.0], [105.0, 1.0]
            ]
          },
        "properties": {
          "prop0": "value0",
          "prop1": 0.0
          }
        },
      { "type": "Feature",
         "geometry": {
           "type": "Polygon",
           "coordinates": [
             [ [100.0, 0.0], [101.0, 0.0], [101.0, 1.0],
               [100.0, 1.0], [100.0, 0.0] ]
             ]
         },
         "properties": {
           "prop0": "value0",
           "prop1": {"this": "that"}
           }
         }
      ]
    }

    map.addLayer({
        'id': 'layerid',
        'type': 'fill',
        'source': {
            'type': 'geojson',
            'data': json_data
        }
    });
});
```

---

**EDIT**

I have also now tried:

**views.py**

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    return render(request, 'map.html', {'path':'/somepath/sample.json'})
```

**map.html**

```
map.on('load', function () {

    // THIS DOES NOT WORK

    $.getJSON({{ path }}, function(data) {
        var json_data = data
    });

    map.addLayer({
        'id': 'layerid',
        'type': 'fill',
        'source': {
            'type': 'geojson',
            'data': json_data
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: It could be much cleaner to put sample.json somewhere on public path and load it asynchronously from javascript instead of passing data through template.

Comment: Is this possible when _/somepath/sample.json_ is a local file?

Comment: sure, just put it somewhere in django static folder

Comment: Ok I just tried passing GeoJSON filepath from the view to the template as the variable `path`, and then called `$.getJSON({{ path }}, function(data) {json_data = data});` with no luck. Do you know of another way?

Comment: All the attempts you tried are ok and should work but you need to start actually debugging them. Check what is actually getting substituted in html and rendered in browser. Log javascript vars in console ect.